# Load Project from GeoPackage not available to user of QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

A colleague of mine is attempting to open a project from a geopackage I have created. The easiest method I found for them to use is to simply follow the following steps: Project -> Open From -> GeoPackage. This way they are able to load in the actual project located within the GeoPackage that contains all the styling, formatting, etc.

However, "Open from" is only giving them the option "PostgreSQL" while on my end I have the additional options of "Oracle" and "Geopackage".

Does anyone know why this is the case, and if there is a way to add these options for them?

They are able to load in the geopackage by dragging and dropping, but none of the formatting and styling is retained since it is loading in all the layers stored in the geopackage instead of the actual project file. I am also aware of creating a connection for them to load in the geopackage layers, but the same problem of no formatting and styling remains.

Also, the version of QGIS does not seem to be an issue as they are on 3.4 and I am on 3.3 so I find it hard to believe that options would be removed in a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the version is the problem! You very likely don't have version 3.3 (this was a nightly build, not a regular version), you probably use QGIS 3.30 „’s-Hertogenbosch“.

Your colleague uses QGIS 3.4 (not the same as 3.40!), a version that was in use in 2019. There are 12(!) major QGIS versions between your installation and that of your colleague, each with many new features.

The option to open a project from a Geopackage was [introduced in QGIS version 3.8](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/index.html#feature-qgis-projects-inside-geopackage-files).

So the only way they can open a project from a Geopackage is to [update to a newer version](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

*Be aware: QGIS version numbers are not in decimal format, so 3.30 is "three dot thirty", not "three dot three-zero". Even version-numbers (3.28, 3.30, 3.32, 3.34 etc.) are regular releases, uneven numbers (3.29, 3.31, 3.33 etc.) are nightly builds for testing purposes! See [QGIS Road Map](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html).*

Comment: Ahh I see! Thanks for the clarification. I am still fairly new in the QGIS realm (was in ESRI before) and just assumed the leading number was the prominent indicator and then the additional numbers past that were smaller updates to the main version.  Does make sense as they mentioned they were in "Madeira" while you were correct, I am in "'s-Hertogenbosch". I'll have them update then! Thanks again

Comment: QGIS has more than 20 years meanwhile and still is in version 3.x, even though there are 3 new releases every year, but counted after the dot. There are no signs yet that a version 4.x will be released, all updates are inside version 3.x